# a)If $f(x)$ is periodic function then is $F(x)$ periodic too? b)If $f(x)$ is odd function than is $F(x)$ even function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

We have $\frac{dF}{dx}=f(x)$ $(x\in R)$

a)If $f(x)$ is periodic function then is $F(x)$ periodic too?

b)If $f(x)$ is odd function than is $F(x)$  even function?

My work.

a)$lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x+h+T)-F(x+T)}{h}$ how continue from here to proof that $F(x)=F(x+T)$?

b)$\frac{dF}{dx}=f(x)$ is odd

$-f(x)=f(-x)$

$f(-x)= $ $lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(-x+h)-F(-x)}{h}=lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(x+h)}{h} $ and can't continue from here.

Comment: For a) consider $g(x) = F(x+T) - F(x) $, for b) consider $F(x)-F(-x)$

Comment: (a) is false unless you impose a condition.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2167311/42969 for the first question, and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357215/42969 for the second question.